# Not able to check linear separability of data in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, linear-programming

I have a training data set. I want to check if that is linearly separable. I am using linear programming for this purpose and using the equations mentioned at this [site](https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/testing-linear-separability-linear-programming-r-glpk/). The data has 11 columns, with last column(11th) having values(0,1) representing result values. Below is the code that I am using:

```
    import os
    import math
    import traceback
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.io as sio
    from scipy.optimize import linprog
    os.system('cls')
    dic  = sio.loadmat('train.mat')
    M = dic.get('M')
    #s0 = np.zeros((1,11),np.int64)
    #s1 = np.zeros((1,11),np.int64)
    if M!=None:
        print(len(M))
        print(len(M[0]))
        m0 = M[M[:,10]==0]
        m1 = M[M[:,10]==1]
        m0 = m0[:,0:10]
        m1 = m1[:,0:10]
        m0 = -1*m0
        o0 = np.ones((len(m0),1),np.int64)
        m0 = np.hstack((m0,o0))
        o1 = -1*np.ones((len(m1),1),np.int64)
        m1 = np.hstack((m1,o1))
        del M
        del dic
        print('del variables')
        A = np.vstack((m1,m0))
        print(A)
        b = -1*np.ones((len(A),1),np.int64)
        print(b)
        c = np.zeros((1,11),np.int64)                     
        print('size c =[',len(c),',',len(c[0]),']')
        print('size A =[',len(A),',',len(A[0]),']')
        print('size b =[',len(b),',',len(b[0]),']')
        res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=(-math.inf, math.inf),options={"disp": True})
        print(res)
```

I get the following error when I run the above code.

```
res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=(-math.inf, math.inf),options={"disp": True})
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_linprog.py", line 993, in linprog
    bounds=bounds, callback=callback, **options)
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_linprog.py", line 594, in _linprog_simplex
    cc = np.concatenate([np.array([0]), cc])
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

So, as stated in the exception, I am setting wrong value of arrays.From what I have understood, c is the seed value for finding the hyper plane and b is R.H.S of equation.So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Print out shape pf c, A_ub and b_ub before the linprog call. The error indicates, that you are not compatible with the needed shapes!

Comment: You array `b` has two dimensions, with the second having a size of `1`. According to [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html), `b_ub` has to be one-dimensional, so try to make it `1-D` instead (check the example at the bottom of the linked page).

Comment: @sascha Size of arrays are : A = [nR,11] , B = [nR,1] , c = [1,11] ; where nR is the a large number.